# Doesnt show the full article

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have some long article to show in an view. So I made a TextBlock and bound Text with Content property.

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid Margin="12,24,12,0"
              Background="White">
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="{Binding Column.Title}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0,0,0,12"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,62,0,10">
                <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"
                           Text="{Binding Column.Content}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

**The last paragrafs of the article:**

[image]

The problem is that it doesn’t show the last paragraphs O_o:

[image]

**What is the problem and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I've had that issue before and I haven't resolved it yet. Do you know how many characters are in the displayed portion? Maybe there is a memory limitation.

Comment: @Toni Petrina It has 3391 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason for this behavior is that any element that must be displayed beyond the area which is larger than 2048x2048 pixels would be clipped by the platform.

Maybe this article can help you : [Creating Scrollable TextBlock for WP7.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx?Redirected=true)